# Estimate model parameters for a process that can abruptly change at some random point in time

Tags: time-series, bayesian, modeling, markov-process

I have two data streams y and x from which I can observe yt and xt at time t. I can always define a specific model yt=f(xt) where f is a non-linear function defined by some parameters, θ.

There is a non-zero chance that the state governing this process may change abruptly. In such a case the parameters of the model change but the relationship yt=f(xt) still holds with the new parameters.

I can estimate the parameters at any time by fitting the model on a period of training data, as long as the process is in a constant state during the training period. My current approach to this is to fit a model, then monitor the residuals for changepoints, if one occurs then I would need to fit a new model. The problem is that a change point could be the result in a change in a single parameter or subset of the parameters and I loose out on the past information when I fit a new model; not only that but the amount of data that I need to train a model from scratch may be longer than the time between two changepoints in certain cases, and it is really important that I catch the changepoints.

What I would like is a model that will tell me at any time what the most likely parameters are, when it is likely that the underlying process has changed, and what the new parameters likely are. My instinct is to use bayesian inference to find something like p(θ|yt,xt, θt-1), but I am not really sure what class of model this would fall under or what type of processes I should be reading about.

Comment: Take a look at the intervention analysis topic in the latest edition of the Box and Jenkins text on time series.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I am not really sure that is what I want.  I can not directly observe the model parameters at any given time (which is what I am most interested in), and I can imagine a case where the underlying process can change but the mean of y would remain the same.

Comment: @Brock I think what you need is a form of threshold regression - a two state model. A useful book on this kind of thing is _State‑space Models with Regime Switching: Classical and Gibbs‑sampling_ by Kim and Nelson. There are various ways of modelling the transition process - the process used to determine the current state, e.g. smooth transition, duration dependence, etc. Check that book out and the related models.

Comment: @GraemeWalsh I think this is what I am looking for.  Is that book the go to for this stuff, or are there other sources that would be worth while having a read through?

Comment: @Brock I'd say any books that have the following keywords would be worth checking out: "non-linear", "threshold", or "switching". Clive Granger has two [books](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/modelling-nonlinear-economic-time-series-9780199587148?cc=no&lang=en&) on non-linear time series methods in the "advanced econometrics" textbooks. Howell Tong also has a [book](https://www.amazon.com/Non-Linear-Time-Dynamical-Approach-Statistical/dp/0198523009) on "non-linear" time series. (1/2)

Comment: @Brock ["Big Judge"](http://eu.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-047189530X.html) has a chapter on "Varying and Random Coefficient Models". Kim and Nelson is probably the best one, but they are all useful. Have a sift through them. (2/2)